# RewriteRule conflict and removing .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in the .htaccess to delete .php at the end of all files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now I need a new rule to redirect:

```
# FROM: www.example.com/ca/blog/first-post  
# TO:   www.example.com/ca/entrada.php?first post      
RewriteRule ^ca/blog/(.*)$ /ca/entrada.php?url=$1[L]
```

It does not work.

I try to add [LR=301] to know where does it go, and to my surprise, it goes to:

```
www.example.com/ca/entrada.php?url=first-post.php/first-post
```

Then, I check if it could be a conflict with another RewriteRule. I discovered that if I delete the first RewriteRule (the one that get rid of .php) the second (the blog one) works fine.

I just know that there is a conflict between the two RewritRule but, where is exactly the problem and how to solve it?

More specifically I would understand that the first rule could add a .php at the end: "www.example.com/ca/entrada.php?url=first-post.php"  But where the "/first-post" at the end comes from?

Comment: Put the second RewriteRule first.

Comment: @Kenney this works, thank you. But I still do not understand why if I put the second RewriteRule second it goes to:  www.example.com/ca/post.php?url=first-post.php/first-post  Why it adds /first-post at the end?

Comment: And with space: `RewriteRule ^ca/blog/(.*)$ /ca/entrada.php?url=$1 [L]` ?

Comment: @Croises: I do not understand, what do you mean? Perhaps you see an error in my comments? I have updated the question

Comment: It's about your 2nd rule missing a space before the `[L]` in `...entrada.php?url=$1[L]`.

Comment: The space before [L] was not the problem. If I add a space nothing changes